# different behaviour on Calendar class in android 4.0 and android 4.1

Tags: android, calendar

The code is:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(mYear, mMonth, mDay);

int week = c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

the calendar was set to 2012/11(NOV)/06

on Android 4.0, the week is 45
while on Android 4.1, it is 46

Can anybody explain this, or tell me the right way to use it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is your mYear, mMonth, mDay pointing to the currentDate ? If so you could just do :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(new Date());
int week = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

If not then set them explicitly :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, mYear);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, mMonth);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, mDay);
int week = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```